# Get a specific record in a table of SQL Lite database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a SQL Lite database in my app. It consist of a table with 3 columns namely, id, keyword and text. The id is int type which is auto-incremented, the keyword and text are of type string. Say for example i have these 3 records in table:

```
id | keyword    | text    
 1 | morning    | "good morning"       
 2 | evening    | "good evening"
 3 | night      | "good night"
```

What i am looking for is a function in format below that returns specific text based on the specific keyword passed as argument to function. Or how could i implement a SELECT sql statememnt in a query to return the specific text based on keyword.

```
    public String getRecord(String search)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    //SELECT text FROM Table WHERE keyword = search
    String query = ("SELECT" + COLUMN_TEXT + " FROM " + TABLE_PREDICTIVES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_KEYWORD + "=\""+ search + "\";");

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();

 //   db.execSQL(query);
   String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("text"));
    db.close();
    return value;
}
```

i have updated the getRecord function; is that how i return the text value from column text based on specific keyword??

Comment: `SELECT text   FROM Table WHERE keyword = search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried with single quotes instead of double?

```
 String query = ("SELECT " + COLUMN_TEXT + " FROM " + TABLE_PREDICTIVES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_KEYWORD + " = '" + search + "';");
```

Comment: you probably also need a space after your `SELECT`.

Comment: Remember i am using Android SQL Lite. The query will work, what i am asking if how do i access the value which the SELECT statement will return?? The purpose of SELECT statement is to return value in COLUMN_TEXT, how do i access this value and return it to function as a string??

Comment: any help from expert on here? want to get this working so i can progress